# How do I make two text elements overlap directly using CSS?

Tags: css

Let's say I have:

```
<div>
  hello
  <div>hello</div>
</div>
```

I'd like the two texts to overlap directly at the same position (aligned center). Doesn't matter which overlaps which.

Is it possible to do this with CSS?

The closest I can get is:

```
<div style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; width: 0">
  hello
  <div style="position: absolute; text-align: center">hello</div>
</div>
```

But this results in one above (vertically) the other, and not centered.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that there's a [`text-shadow` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/CR-css3-text-20030514/#text-shadows) which is supported in [most browsers](http://caniuse.com/css-textshadow), if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @thirtydot: close, I'm actually trying to apply a text shadow to some gradient text. The gradient text is created with CSS background image clipping, so it's actually part of the background, thus any text-shadow I apply to that will appear on top of the background. That's why I need to make it the background of a second element that's on top of the text with shadow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `top: 0; width: 100%` to the inner `div`:

```
<div style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center">
    hello
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100%">hello</div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what `width: 0` was doing on the outer `div`, so I removed it.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Xprtd/

Answer (score 1):

**Tested in browser IE, FF, Chrome...**

```
<div style="background:red;position: relative;text-align:center;width:100%;">
    <div style="color:Green;position:relative;">hello
        <div style="position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;">hello</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `top:0px;` style to second div...

Answer (score 0):

Try giving them equal width, outer - width: auto or something, inner - 100%.
You should also think about left:0;top:0 for the absolutely positioned div.

Answer (score 0):

The style of the second div don't care.

html

```
<div class="styleDiv">
  hello
  <div>hello</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.styleDiv {
    line-height: 4px; /* 0px if you want to overlaps completly */
    text-align: center;
}
```

Then, adjust the `line-height`